# What is the difference between JoinQueryOver and JoinAlias?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I need to know what is the difference between JoinQueryOver and JoinAlias, and when to use each?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Functionally they do the same thing, create a join to another entity. The only difference is what they return. JoinQueryOver returns a new QueryOver with the current entity being the entity joined, while JoinAlias returns the original QueryOver that has the current entity as the original root entity.

Whichever one you use is a matter of personal taste:
(from http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryqueryover)

```
IQueryOver<Cat,Kitten> catQuery =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>()
        .JoinQueryOver<Kitten>(c => c.Kittens)
            .Where(k => k.Name == "Tiddles");
```

and

```
Cat catAlias = null;
Kitten kittenAlias = null;
IQueryOver<Cat,Cat> catQuery =
    session.QueryOver<Cat>(() => catAlias)
        .JoinAlias(() => catAlias.Kittens, () => kittenAlias)
        .Where(() => kittenAlias.Name == "Tiddles");
```

Are functionally the same. Note how the kittenAlias is expressly referenced in the second query.

Comment: Note that in the second example you have to declare the aliases `Kitten kittenAlias = null;` and `Cat catAlias = null;` earlier. I find it messy, so I don't use `JoinAlias` unless it's necessary.

Comment: Thank you @foka for clarifying this. I missed this and was wondering why it didn't work.

Answer (score 14):

[QueryOver Series - Part 2: Basics and Joining by Andrew Whitaker](http://blog.andrewawhitaker.com/blog/2014/03/16/queryover-series-part-2-basics/) gives a very good explanation:

> Summary:
>
> - `IQueryOver` is a generic type with two type parameters `TRoot` and `TSubType`
> - `.Select` operates on `TRoot` while other QueryOver methods operate on `TSubType`.
> - `TRoot` stays the same as you’re building a query, but `TSubType` changes when you join using `JoinQueryOver`
> - `JoinQueryOver` and `JoinAlias` add joins to your query. `JoinAlias` doesn’t change `TSubType`, but `JoinQueryOver` does.
> - You can use aliases when building a query to refer to properties that don’t belong to `TRoot` or `TSubType`