# JoinQueryOver with multiple tables with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, lambda, entities

I can't build the lambda expressions in NHibernate JoinQueryOver that solve the SQL command below:

```
SELECT 
    A.STATUS,
    B.NUMBER,
    B.OTHER_NUMBER,
    A.Date01,
    A.Date02
FROM 
    B, 
    C, 
    A
WHERE
        A.ID = C.ID
    AND     B.ID = C.ID
```

All tables in SQL command above are in Entities with same name (A, B, C) and the inner join is in WHERE clause.

How can I build the NHibernate lambda query?

Thanks,

Roosevelt

Answer (score 4):

```
A a = null;
B b = null;
var result = session.QueryOver<C>()
    .JoinAlias(c => c.A, () => a)
    .JoinAlias(c => c.B, () => b)
    .Select(c => a.Status, c => b.Number, c => b.Other_Number, c => a.Date01, c => a.Date02 )
    .List<object[]>();
```

Comment: This will not work in case when we need to set up conditions for A or B entities. Nhibernate will not find these aliases for the query

Comment: @Anubis sorry i don't understand. `.Where(() => a.Prop == Something)` works for me

Comment: Fwiw, the OP did ask for `.JoinQueryOver` rather than `JoinAlias`.

Comment: @ruffin JoinAlias and JoinQueryOver are the same for all intents and purposes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416560/what-is-the-difference-between-joinqueryover-and-joinalias