# NHibernate: Could not resolve property error

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am trying to do a query like:

```
  var a = session.QueryOver<Site>()
                  .SelectList(
                  x => x.Select(p => p.SiteName)
                 .Select(p => p.SiteId).Select(p => p.RegionLocation.City))
                 .List<object[]>();
```

but I get the error

`could not resolve property: RegionLocation.City of: Entities.Site`

The property exists and I can retrieve it using LINQ but QueryOver does not work. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You might need to join Site and RegionLocation.

Comment: @henginy I tried that too using JoinQueryOver but couldn't get it to work

Comment: JoinAlias has a simpler syntax, works better for me.
This might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5416560/82047

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember, with QueryOver, you have to join all entities in the association in order to be able to access it's properties.

This means you ought to do something like:
(notice the `.JoinQueryOver`)

```
var a = session.QueryOver<Site>()
             .JoinQueryOver(s => s.RegionLocation)
             .SelectList(
                x => x.Select(p => p.SiteName)
                      .Select(p => p.SiteId)
                      .Select(p => p.RegionLocation.City))
             .List<object[]>();
```

Or maybe this will work:

```
RegionLocation regionLocationAlias = null;
var a = session.QueryOver<Site>()
             .JoinAlias(s => s.RegionLocation, () => regionLocationAlias)
             .SelectList(
                x => x.Select(p => p.SiteName)
                      .Select(p => p.SiteId)
                      .Select(() => regionLocationAlias.City))
             .List<object[]>();
```

Also you might want to have a look at https://github.com/davybrion/NHibernateWorkshop/tree/master/NHibernateWorkshop
There's lots of great examples!

Specifically for your problem, have a look at: https://github.com/davybrion/NHibernateWorkshop/blob/master/NHibernateWorkshop/Querying/QueryOver/Projecting.cs