# How to do more than one level projection in query over?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I tired this

```
respondentSanctionSubquery = respondentSanctionSubquery.Select(x => x.Respondent.Incident.Id);
```

but i got this exception :
[image]

i have 3 entities not 2 entities :

```
class Respondent
{
public IncidentObj{get;set;}
}
class Incident
{
public int Id{get;set;}
}
class RespondentSanction
{
public Respondent RespondentObj{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do join between the entities using Join alias

```
respondentSanctionSubquery = 
    respondentSanctionSubquery
        .JoinAlias(x => x.RespondentObj)
        .JoinAlias(resp => resp.IncidentObj)
        .Select(inc => inc.Id);
```

for more information please check this URL :[What is the difference between JoinQueryOver and JoinAlias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416560/what-is-the-difference-between-joinqueryover-and-joinalias)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a `JOIN` in order to do a projection like that:

```
respondentSanctionSubquery = 
    respondentSanctionSubquery
        .JoinQueryOver(x => x.RespondentObj)
        .JoinQueryOver(resp => resp.IncidentObj)
        .Select(inc => inc.Id);
```

Comment: This work only with two entity , but I have 3 entities related with each other please find the updated question .

Comment: also please not the I'm trying to do this in Sub Query .(this one respondentSanctionSubquery  is sub query ).

Comment: Actually i tired this but it dose not work , but i find the solution i used .JoinAlias instead of JoinQueryOver.

Comment: anyway Andrew thank you for your help . I appreciate your help

Comment: now the query can't resolve the RespondentSanction properties

Comment: @sohaib: Oh, I see. You must be selecting other properties that aren't in your question. In that case, `JoinAlias` is a better option.

Comment: no the other properties  I used them in where statement not in selection :)

Comment: @sohaib: I see-- in that case you can put the `Where` clauses right after the `respondentSanctionSubquery`, but `JoinAlias` is easier to use here and if it works, I'd stick with it. Glad you figured it out

Answer (score 1):

You have to join other entities also to the main query (as follows),

```
X x = null; 
Respondent respondent = null;
Incident incident = null;

respondentSanctionSubquery = respondentSanctionSubquery
        .JoinQueryOver(() => x.Respondent , () => respondent)
        .JoinQueryOver(() => respondent.Incident , () => incident )
        .Select(r => incident.Id);
```

or else you might want to go for subqueries,

```
X x = null; 
Respondent respondent = null;
Incident incident = null;

    var subQuery = (QueryOver<Respondent>)session.QueryOver<Respondent>(() => respondent)
                  .JoinQueryOver(() => respondent.Incident , () => incident )
                  .Where(() => respondent.Id == x.Respondent.Id)
                  .Select(r => incident.Id);

    var query = session.QueryOver(() => x)
                .SelectList(l => l.SelectSubQuery(subQuery));
```

Comment: i tried this but i got this exception 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
'

Comment: Obviously you have more than one incident per x and that's the reason you are getting this error, so you probably should go for the first option.

Comment: could you please see the question again i did some changes on it .

Comment: Also i tired the first solution but another problem is appeared . I got this exception 'could not resolve property: StartDate of: Entities.Incident'              note that the Start Date is exist in the RespondentSanction entity .any advice please ?

Comment: Are you sure your mapping is in order? Sounds like issue with mapping of the start date.